# How can I get GPG Agent to cache my password?

Tags: password, git, gnupg

I'm a developer, and I commonly sign my Git commits with my GPG key. I've been able to get GPG Agent working properly on OSX so that it only asks me for my password once per day, but I'm having problems getting the same thing working on Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's what I'm doing:

- I've got my GPG keys setup / etc.
- I'm in a Git directory.
- I add some files to Git.
- I then go to commit them (`git commit`), and get a GPG password request that looks like this:

  ```
  $ git ci

  You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
  user: "Randall Degges <r@rdegges.com>"
  4096-bit RSA key, ID 8F700DA2, created 2016-04-05

  [master 1740961] blah
   1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
  ```

The problem is: every single time I do a commit, I'm re-prompted for my GPG password again.

What I'd like to do is configure GPG Agent to cache my password for 1 full day, so it only needs to be entered once.

I've read through tons of documentation and blog posts, and here's what I've tried so far...

First, I modified my `~/.zshrc` file (I use zsh) to set the following:

```
# GPG Agent
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPGKEY=8F700DA2
```

Now, from what I read, this alone should do the trick after restarting gpg-agent, but it does not.

So, the next thing I did was I defined a `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file as explained in the `man gpg-agent` page:

```
# Set the default cache time to 1 day.
default-cache-ttl       86400
default-cache-ttl-ssh   86400

# Set the max cache time to 30 days.
max-cache-ttl           2592000
max-cache-ttl-ssh       2592000
```

This also has no effect.

I've also tried various blog methods, etc., but nothing seems to work. Can someone give me some pointers to things I might be missing?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In addition to setting up the cache times in `gpg-agent.conf`, you also have to make sure GnuPG is actually interfacing the `gpg-agent`. GnuPG 2 and upwards generally does, but the GnuPG 1 branch does not. By default git is using the `gpg` binary, which (at the time of writing this answer) still is GnuPG 1, while GnuPG 2 is installed as `gpg2` on most systems.

In the end, you have two possibilities:

- [set up git to use `gpg2`](https://superuser.com/q/887110/102155) by changing the git configuration:

  ```
  git config --global gpg.program gpg2
  ```
- set up `gpg`(GnuPG 1) to use `gpg-agent` by adding `use-agent` to `gpg.conf`

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 `gpg --version` = `gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.19`.

Comment: very useful information that I'm not able to find this anywhere. Good question by the poster too.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer, you can also just change the default `gpg` in your system to `gpg2` rather than `gpg1`.

If `git config --global gpg.program gpg2` works for you, but you don't want to leave that in your git config (in my case because I use the same config on macOS) then you can just swap the default `gpg` out.

I followed the guide [here](https://makandracards.com/aslamk/28305-how-to-change-the-default-gnupg-version-from-gpg-to-gpg2), which was just:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/gpg /usr/bin/gpg1
$ sudo update-alternatives --verbose --install /usr/bin/gpg gnupg /usr/bin/gpg2 50
```

This makes `gpg1` the old `gpg` binary, and symlinks `/usr/bin/gpg -> /usr/bin/gpg2` (with name gnupg and priority 50).

Changing the default `gpg` could in theory break some packages on your system, but Debian Stretch (the current stable version of Debian) [sets `gpg2` as the default `gpg`](https://www.debian.org/News/2017/20170617) in a similar way, so you shouldn't have too many problems.